# Angular - clear local storage on hard refresh

Tags: angular, caching, local-storage

I'm looking for a way to remove something from local storage but ONLY on a hard refresh (ctrl + F5), not a normal refresh, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it could be helpful

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
keydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event && event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 116) {
        window.localStorage.clear();
    }
}
```